# Autocomplete action on multile fileds from Api -DRF

Tags: jquery, ajax, django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

I am trying to filter on the api list using auto-completion.I am able to filter on single field but not on multiple fields.

In html file-

```
<div class="form-group">
        <b>Player</b>
        <input resource="{% url 'api:player-list'%}" id="search_player_autocomplete" class="form-control"
               placeholder="-type player-">
    </div>
```

In js file -

```
function attachplayerAutoCompleteList(plasListInput, hiddenPlasIdInput){

    $(plasListInput).autocomplete({
        source: function( request, response ) {
            $.ajax({
                url: $(plasListInput).attr('resource'),
                dataType: 'json',
                data: {
                    first_name: request.term,
                    ordering: 'last_name'
                },
                success: function(data) {
                    response($.map( data, function( item ) {
                        return {
                               ----
                               }
                });
```

In above code..data: {
                        first_name: request.term,
                        ordering: 'last_name'
                    },

The request.term searches in first name of the list.but I want to use auto-complete on one more field named last_name from the fields.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue by adding a filter for a particular field for first_name and last_name.